# i want solveError in Django

Tags: python, django, webserver

I still haven't solved this fall. I don't know what this error means. Please fix this error.

### Problem:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7501a.png)

```
path('/polls', views.polls, name='polls'),

\src\fistsite\urls.py", line 7, in module

AttributeError:   module 'polls.views' has no attribute 'polls'
```

### Source Code

urls.py-fistsite

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/polls', views.polls, name='polls'),
    path('/admin', views.admin, name='admin')
]
```

urls.py-polls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/result/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote')
]
```

views.py-polls

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from polls.models import Question, Choice

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list':latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice.set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html',{
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/result.html', {'question': question})
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is You are using views.polls but in your views.py, you have index, detail, votes and result. There is no polls in views.py.
Instead, you need to include all the urlpatterns present in the polls app,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', views.admin, name='admin'),
]
```

Go through the official docs all over again.